# Jmeter beanscript get currentTime doesnt work

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am new to Jmeter. create a Jsr223 postprocessor and select language as Bsh.

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

long mill = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info(mill);
```

output:

```
 ERROR - jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Date;  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  long mill = System.c . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method info( long ) not found in class'org.apache.log.Logger' : at Line: 5 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Date;  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  long mill = System.c . . . '' : log .info ( mill ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Date;  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  long mill = System.c . . . '' at line number 5
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:92)
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:206)
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:776)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please advise a fix. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you aware of [__time() JMeter function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) which can output current time in the different formats?

---

If you still want to do it in Beanshell  be informed that you cannot print a [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) value directly to *jmeter.log* file, you need to cast it to String first using one of the following approaches

- `log.info(String.valueOf(mill));`
- `log.info(Long.toString(mill));`
- `log.info("Current time is: " + mill);`

You can get a "good" Beanshell error by putting your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

[image: JMeter beanshell try catch]